# BGE: How do I hide the player HUD from other players or cameras?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'me starting work on a FPS and want it to support two local players. I will be using low poly characters, but I,d like to be able to create higher poly fps arms and a HUD system that would be hidden from the other player. Does anyone know how to do this? my guess is it involves coding and perhaps multiple scenes.

thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you want the "support two local players" work? Is it split screen?

Comment: yes it will be splitscreen multiplayer. @Monster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that the viewports will not change during the game (unless you explicitly want that).

[image]

This allows you to design your HUD as single viewport.

You place the player specific information where it matches the according viewport of the level scene. An area for shared information can be useful too.

[image]

When you add the HUD it projects the HUD over both viewports.

[image]

You do that with a scene actuator in add overlay mode. I suggest to use an separate empty that does that (and only that).

[image]

This will result in a nice combination of all three cameras. With a little designing skills you make the audience think there are two or even three HUDs.

[image]

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *overlay scene* in the game logics. I played around with that and you can find something easily on the internet. Good luck and have fun.

Some more details:
In the *game logics* you can add an *always sensor* and connect it to the *add overlay scene* node. I think the connection has to be a *python script* but i'm not shure. Then you can code the properties of the player and connect them via scripting to the overlay hud.

I watched this videos some time ago and i think they are very good for you. They are for 2.6 but i think the bge didn't change *that* much...
[Creating a HUD in bge](https://youtu.be/Rrihz2HFoSE)

Personally i hope the game logics get an upgrade. They should be more like a node editor as in UE4... But i think i have to wait a bit longer...

I hope that helped. Later i can try out again for you and send some screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE sirjofri!  Please add some more details to your answer on how to use *overlay scene*.  "You can find something on the internet" doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Is that better now?